# UIPageControl in PageViewController which is embedded with NavigationController

Tags: swift, xcode

I tried my best to find a solution or a close one, but didn't. I hope this is not getting down voted.

I have a PageViewController which is embedded in NavigationController. I want a UIPageControl at the top bar.

Here is what I've tried and found answers. In UIPageViewControllerDataSource there is two methods, presentationIndex and presentationCount. By implementing this it will automatic set a pagecontrol at the bottom of the screen.

I created an instance of UIPageControl in the class and then tried with navigationBar.addSubview and navigationItem.addSubview. Which doesnt work. The only thing I haven't tried is to drag a PageControl object to my ViewController in storyboard.

I want to achieve this with code. How?